# Battery to light 100W bulb

Tags: power

I want to light electric bulb of 100W AC for 2 hours, whats the minimum power battery should I use for such bulb? And please suggest some battery of that power.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate battery life with a given load?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122741/how-to-calculate-battery-life-with-a-given-load)

Comment: Requests for product suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: That's a bad idea.   Get an LED lamp instead - it will use less power for equivalent light output, and you should be able to find a model for direct DC operation.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to light electric bulb of 100W AC for 2 hours, whats the
>   minimum power battery should I use for such bulb?

If you want to deliver 100 watts to your bulb then the battery has to be capable of supplying 100 watts. It's as simple as that. For two hours that's an energy of 200 watt-hours or 720,000 joules.

If the battery and bulb are (say) 12 volt rated, that's a current of 8.333 amps so your starting point is a battery of 16.666 ampere hours but you probably need to go twice this amount to maintain a fairly regular brightness over the two hours.

There isn't enough information to make any recommendations and stack exchange doesn't tolerate requests for product recommendations usually.